# Unable to load geometry field from geodataframe to a PostgreSQL table 'geometry' field

Tags: python, postgresql, geopandas

I am trying to load a geodataframe to a PostgreSQL table, but I am struggling with the geometry field.

First I read feature class using Geopandas:

```
geodata = (r'path_to_gdb', driver='FileGDB', layer='test')
```

Then I try to export it to an existing PostgreSQL table called "vml_polygs":

```
for index, row in geodata.iterrows():
    load_to_pg = "INSERT INTO public.vml_polygs VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, ST_GeomFromText('{4}'::GEOMETRY,27700));".format(index, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
    cursor.execute(load_to_pg)
    con.commit()
```

row[3] contains the geometry of the geodataframe. It's in WKT. With the expression `ST_GeomFromText('{4}'::GEOMETRY,27700)`I am trying to convert it to WKB since I believe that's the required format of the geometry for PostgresSQL (please, correct me here if I'm wrong).

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "footprint.py", line 72, in <module>
    cursor.execute(load_to_pg)
psycopg2.InternalError: parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "...100000001030000000100000005000000713D" <-- parse error at position 48 within geometry
```

And if I try with the following instruction:

```
load_to_pg = "INSERT INTO public.vml_polygs VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, ST_GeomFromText({4}, 27700));".format(index, row[0], row[1], row[2], str(row[3]))
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "footprint.py", line 71, in <module>
    cursor.execute(load_to_pg)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "306481.5500000007"
LINE 1: ...882934, ST_GeomFromText(MULTIPOLYGON (((452640.71 306481.550...
```

Comment: Don't use `format` to general SQL. [Use parameterized queries.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/902408/1394393) Formatting in this manner creates security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I think you should look into the the `geodata.to_sql` method

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out what the right instruction is. Please, see below:

```
   load_to_pg = "INSERT INTO public.vml_polygs (objectid, fcode, shape_length, shape_area, geom) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, ST_GeomFromText('{4}', 27700));".format(index, row[0], row[1], row[2], str(row[3]))
```